# FacebookException : Failed to copy image

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, mobile-application, facebook-exception

I am getting this error while trying to use the Facebook SDK for Android.

This is my execute call:

```
new getBitmapFromUrl().execute("https://fs02.androidpit.info/userfiles/4110382/image/Android/android-6-0-marshmallow-hero-w782.jpg");
```

My async code:

```
public class getBitmapFromUrl extends AsyncTask<String,String,Bitmap>{
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setDoInput(true);
            InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);

        SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(bitmap)
                .build();
        SharePhotoContent sharePhotoContent = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(sharePhoto)
                .build();
 //shareButton is the facebookSdk default share button to call shareDialog
        shareButton.setShareContent(sharePhotoContent);
    }
}
```

This is my callback method:

```
shareButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
        Log.e("Status", result.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        Log.e("Status", error.toString());
    }
});
```

And my onActivity callback:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

My Manifest code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <provider
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1507510099556071"
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"/>
</application>
```

If my code isn't correct, please suggest a good example. :-)

Comment: What you actually want? Do you want to share the Image to Facebook?

Comment: yes ! I am learning facebook sdk documentation .so i tried the sharePhotoContent method but it shows me failed to copy error!!

Comment: kindly post your manifest snippet pls

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan see the edit of my post,thanks

Comment: do you have Facebook share button for sharing. or native button ?

Comment: check my answer, if it works for you. @prasanth

Answer (score 2):

just change the exported attribute to true and it will work

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProvider355198514515820"
              android:name="com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider"
              android:exported="true"/>
```

Comment: Yes. sure you set android:exported="true"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. But need some minor tweaks.

> Hope you have not added the correct bitmap for sharing. Check below
>   things in your code.
>
> In Post execute you added "mBitmap". You need to add "bitmap" which
>   you received from the params.

On your onCreate kindly call and initiate the Facebook SDK and share dialog. Check below sample.

// Declaration

```
CallbackManager callbackManager;
ShareDialog shareDialog;
```

// Below should go under oncreate.

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
// Initiate share by downloading the image.
        new getBitmapFromUrl().execute("https://fs02.androidpit.info/userfiles/4110382/image/Android/android-6-0-marshmallow-hero-w782.jpg");
      }
    });
```

// Download file from the path and return the Bitmap.

```
public class getBitmapFromUrl extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
  Bitmap bitmap = null;
  URL url = null;
  try {
    url = new URL(params[0]);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setDoInput(true);
    InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return bitmap;
}
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
      super.onPostExecute(bitmap);

      SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder()
              .setBitmap(bitmap)
              .build();
      SharePhotoContent sharePhotoContent = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
              .addPhoto(sharePhoto)
              .build();
//      shareButton.setShareContent(sharePhotoContent);
      shareDialog.show(sharePhotoContent);
    }
  }
```

Queries let me know.!

Comment: I have done all the above !!But I  shared the video and link to facebook by using the sdk and sandbox is enable .So kindly send me the code for bitmap in  setBitmap(bitmap).I think bitmap conversion is my problem

Comment: I can't find the changes .It look same code that i posted on the question .Could you help me out.

Comment: You are using the facebook default share button. But i'm using android native button. that is the only difference. Try follow up my code using the native android button for share.

Answer (score 0):

all above you have to done.

then  the most important is that you have to make the file path like : `"content://media/external/images/media/159745"` to let the **com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider** can resolve this media.